# phpMyAdmin on GAE - Authentication

Tags: php, google-app-engine, phpmyadmin

I have setup phpmyadmin on GAE using the tutorial provided @ https://gaeforphp-blog.appspot.com/2013/05/26/setting-up-phpmyadmin-on-app-engine/

The version of the app (phpmyadmin) can be accessed without problems, but I cannot seem to authenticate against my Cloud SQL instance.

I have tried both cookie and config type authentication without success. However I have discovered, with cookie auth, after submitting the username password, the page just reloads without errors.

If I use config auth, I get the following error on the page:

## 2002 - Unable to find the socket transport "tcp" - did you forget to enable it when you configured PHP?

The server is not responding (or the local server's socket is not correctly configured).

All google searches point me to ssl library in php. Has anyone been able to get phpmyadmin to work on GAE?

Would have preferred if the actual blog entry (@ gaeforphp-blog.appspot.com) would support comments to ask the question to the Author, unfortunately thats not the case.

Comment: I have written [this tutorial for phpmyadmin local installation](http://novelcode.blogspot.in/2013/07/phpmyadmin-on-google-app-engine-part-1.html). You can take a look at it and see if it helps you out. I'll come back when I successfully complete the deployment tutorial

Comment: This tutorial should help you out. ***[Install phpMyAdmin on Google App Engine](http://novelcode.blogspot.com/2013/07/phpmyadmin-on-google-app-engine-part-2_16.html).***

Answer (score 0):

So you're seeing this error because the connection string you're using is not correct, and we don't know you're trying to connect to CloudSQL.

If you're using mysql make sure you have the ':/cloudsql/' in front of the instance name.

Didn't know that blog didn't accept comments - i'll fix that.

Comment: Using mysql extension with host `:/cloudsql/app-id:instance-id` works for me. Using mysqli extension with host `/cloudsql/app-id:instance-id` throws error 2002. Why is it?

Comment: @Stuart Do I need the colon in front of "/cloudsql/app-id:instance-id" ? I am using mysqli

Comment: I have tried with colon + mysql and without colon + mysqli and both settings I am not able to login.

Comment: with mysqli don't forget the socket is about the 6th parameter in the list. http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.construct.php

Comment: I have setup a template of the phpmyadmin source for GAE @ https://github.com/jeffery/phpmyadmin-gae . If anyone can try and see if it works for them, I would much appreciate it.

Comment: after much mucking around, the solution was to use the config $cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowRoot'] = true; as I was logging in with root user. But that still doesn't explain why I couldn't login with a normal user account which I had granted privileges to.

Answer (score 0):

This were the lines o changed on my `phpMyAdmin 4.1.6.0 config.inc.php` file:

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = ':/cloudsql/<project-id>:<cloudsql-instance>';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension'] = 'mysql';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = true;
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['connect_type'] = 'socket';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowRoot'] = true;
```

And then I added the following lines:

```
$cfg['McryptDisableWarning'] = true;
$cfg['PmaNoRelation_DisableWarning'] = true;
$cfg['ExecTimeLimit'] = 60;
$cfg['CheckConfigurationPermissions'] = false;
```

Considerations:

- By changing `$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword']` to `true` you are allowing anyone to login as `root` with no password. So you might want using this just for the first login to create a new user/password with limited privileges and then change it to `false` again (or you might use the Could Console and do not change this at all).
- The `$cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension'] = 'mysql'` actually did the trick for me. I do not know why, but seems mysqli was not enabled on my php config file.

Links I used:

- [https://gae-php-tips.appspot.com/2013/05/26/setting-up-phpmyadmin-on-app-engine/](http://novelcode.blogspot.com.br/2013/07/phpmyadmin-on-google-app-engine-part-1.html)
- http://novelcode.blogspot.com.br/2013/07/phpmyadmin-on-google-app-engine-part-1.html
- [http://novelcode.blogspot.com.br/2013/07/phpmyadmin-on-google-app-engine-part-2_16.html](http://novelcode.blogspot.com.br/2013/07/phpmyadmin-on-google-app-engine-part-1.html)
- [https://github.com/jeffery/phpmyadmin-gae](http://novelcode.blogspot.com.br/2013/07/phpmyadmin-on-google-app-engine-part-1.html)

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that worked for me is the following configuration.

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'cookie';
/* Server parameters */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['socket'] = '/cloudsql/project-id:db-instance';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['connect_type'] = 'socket';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension'] = 'mysql';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['compress'] = false;
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = true;
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowRoot'] = true;

$cfg['McryptDisableWarning'] = true;
$cfg['PmaNoRelation_DisableWarning'] = true;
$cfg['ExecTimeLimit'] = 60;
$cfg['CheckConfigurationPermissions'] = false;
```

All other configurations failed with all kinds of error messages. From socket not found to gethostbyaddr errors etc. Good luck!