# #2002 - Unable to find the socket transport "tcp"

Tags: php, mysql, sockets, mysqli, tcp

> 2002 - Unable to find the socket transport "TCP" - did you forget to enable it when you configured PHP? — The server is not responding (or the local server's socket not set correctly.).

Can you please help me what the meaning of this error is? I'm a beginner in MySQL and I do not know **where to should I go to solve this**. I'm currently developing my website right now when I encountered this. Your help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Put the code that is generating the error :)

Comment: right there, it's my database connection syntax

Comment: See this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17645127/phpmyadmin-on-gae-authentication